# Does Firebase Cloud Messaging depend on the package name?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to know if package name, defined on Firebase project console, is tightly related to Firebase Cloud Message successful delivery or it's just a helper for creating google-services.json file.

On Firebase console, once created it can't be renamed.

In my case I created a project at Firebase console named, by mistake,  **son**.example.firecm instead of **com**.example.firecm as defined on my Android Studio Project.

My Android project was not compiling cause gap on spelling at google-services.json.

Once renamed package name to com.example.firecm, it compiled but not sure if it will receive Firebase Cloud Messages or not cause difference between Firebase console project package definition at Android Studio project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I did further research on the same.

I found that if package name defined on Firebase Console isn't the same as defined on Gradle and Manifest of the APP,  then the APP **won't** be able to receive Notifications sent from Firebase Console.

In guess that in some way it's logic that package name must match in order to Android lunch the correct APP once notification arrives.

To sumarize, it's **mandatory** that both names matches.

I invite to test by yourself and keep and eye on package names for project success.

Answer (score 6):

Having the right package name is important for several services, though not FCM specifically, other than getting it right in the `google-services.json` as you found. FCM uses the project number to identify the app, which will be read from the JSON file.

The best thing to do is just to connect a new Android app to your [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com) project with the correct package name, and download the updated `google-services.json`. It wont hurt to have the other package name connected (and once the console allows deleting connected apps, you should be able to remove it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain for which services Firebase console package name and Android Studio Project package name are mandatory to match?

Comment: Most of the Firebase labelled services are OK. Invites needs it in some cases, and any Google service using auth - Google Sign In for example.