# Using an existing FCM project (and app) settings for a new app instance

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have to write an entire app (that uses FCM) from scratch. However, I do not want to modify anything in the current Firebase Console project. Is there a way to develop a new app without adding it as an app to the Firebase Console, but instead use the google-services.json (and the rest of the settings of the current app? (the package name is the same).

Answer (score 0):

If the package name is the same as an existing app, and you use the same `google-services.json`, how is Firebase supposed to know which of the two apps to deliver each message to?

An app is only allowed to send messages/receive messages if it is known to the Firebase project. Each app within a project must have a unique package name/application ID.

Also see:

- [Does Firebase Cloud Messaging depend on the package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403958/does-firebase-cloud-messaging-depend-on-the-package-name)
- [Android:Which one to use for package name? Manifest's packagename or Gradle applicationId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38347268/androidwhich-one-to-use-for-package-name-manifests-packagename-or-gradle-appl)
- [Which is the package name on the build gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466006/which-is-the-package-name-on-the-build-gradle)